# Repeat the navigation function in the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have managed to put together a [responsive menu](http://jsfiddle.net/c2webdev/Pb8Ts/1/) with the help from the internet.

I've need it to sit in the footer as well, but to be controlled sepratley, I have copied it and placed it in the footer but I can't seem to get it right.

Can you assist?

Thanks

```
<nav class="clearfix">
<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
<ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item8</a></li>
         <form id="search-form" action="#" method="get" >

             <div id="search-outer">                    
        <input id="search-input" type="text" type="text" name="q" value="Site search" onfocus="if (this.value=='Site search') { this.value=''; };return true;" /><input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
          </div>

      </form>
    </ul>


</nav>
```

Comment: BTW: Use the `{}` button, not the `""` button for code blocks.

Comment: Also, your HTML is not valid.  You can't have `<a>` and a `<form>` as direct children of the `<ul>` like that.

Comment: You are using an ID, `id="pull"`.  These must be *unique*!  Change that to a class, or use a different ID in the footer.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I copied the html, css and JS and changed the ID and it didn't work which is why i put the original up..

Comment: Did you remember to change/add the ID in the JavaScript and the CSS?  Maybe try using a class instead of an ID?

Comment: Yep changed all the id in both JS and CSS, and don't know what else to do........?